# Call Array 2D From Another Method Same Class - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, methods, call

I Have Code:

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class tokoKomputer
{
    public:
        void notebook();
        void printNotebook();
};

void tokoKomputer::notebook()
{
    string notebook[][8]=
    {
        {"MERK", "NO SERI", "HARGA", "STOK", "MEMORY", "HDD", "GPU", "DISPLAY"},
        {"Asus", "ASN0002", "2500000", "9", "1GB", "250GB", "128MB", "10"},
        {"Fujitsu", "FJN0001", "5500000", "12", "1GB", "320GB", "256MB", "14"},
        {"Fujitsu", "FJN0005", "6500000", "4", "4GB", "250GB", "1GB", "14"}
    };  
}

void tokoKomputer::printNotebook()
{
    cout<<notebook[1][3]<<endl;
    cout<<notebook[2][3]<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    tokoKomputer run;
    run.printNotebook;
}
```

but, if i compile the code
ubuntu terminal always give me messages

```
coba.cpp:33:18: error: invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’ for array subscript
coba.cpp:34:18: error: invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’ for array subscript
```

what the errors?
please give me hit to resolved the code

thx

Comment: `notebook[][8]` should be member of class, its local to the function you defined in

Comment: Why do you think you should be able to access that array? It is local to an entirely different function. I suggest you make it a static member. (static as it seems to be hard coded to always contain the same values).

Answer (score 2):

string notebook[][8]  is local to your method, you either need to pass around a reference or just have a private notebook[][] variable for your class.

```
notebook[1][3]
notebook[2][3]
```

the above are not defined within the scope of printNotebook as

```
string notebook[][8]
```

goes out of scope after the notebook() method ends.

Edit: make sure you rename it as you can't have a method and variable member with the same name

Edit again: here's some sample code to get your example on it's feet, this is probably **NOT** the easiest or best way to do it at all, but it **does** compile and work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class tokoKomputer
{
    public:
        void notebook();
        void printNotebook();
        string myNotebook[4][8];  
};

void tokoKomputer::notebook()
{
    string myTempNotebook[4][8] = {
        {"MERK", "NO SERI", "HARGA", "STOK", "MEMORY", "HDD", "GPU", "DISPLAY"},
        {"Asus", "ASN0002", "2500000", "9", "1GB", "250GB", "128MB", "10"},
        {"Fujitsu", "FJN0001", "5500000", "12", "1GB", "320GB", "256MB", "14"},
        {"Fujitsu", "FJN0005", "6500000", "4", "4GB", "250GB", "1GB", "14"}
    };  // This syntax will only work for initializing an array, not setting it later

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++)
        {
            myNotebook[i][j] = myTempNotebook[i][j];
        }
    }

};

void tokoKomputer::printNotebook()
{
    cout << myNotebook[1][3] << endl;
    cout << myNotebook[2][3] << endl;
};

int main()
{
    tokoKomputer run;
    run.notebook();
    run.printNotebook();
    string hello;
    cin >> hello;  // this was just here to keep console open
};
```

Comment: by the way, this will cause a name collision.

Comment: In C++ member function and data member in same namespace.

Comment: yes, forgot to mention that you will want to consider a different naming convention.

Comment: so what should I do, if I want to call a 2d array of different methods in the same class, please answare with example code

Comment: please comment if any changes are needed as mentioned in question I'm slightly rusty in c++, I'll remove extraneous comments and such when an answer is accepted

Comment: I just compile your code

but i got the error again:

coba.cpp: 22:5: warning: extended initializer lists only available with-std = c + +0 x or-std = gnu + +0 x [enabled by default]
coba.cpp: 22:5: error: assigning to an array from an initializer list

Comment: yes I figured there would be a problem with the syntax. I think you can only initialize an array that way, but can't set it. must do it differently.  Check out the comments I added to the code

Comment: do you have a code like this and can be compiled

I've learned if there is no successful example
sory

Comment: Here, I modified it to where it compiles and run on my vs2010 setup and outputs the expected values